# Reading in CAN data into Python

Tags: python, structure, can-bus

I am trying to read in some data that was defined in the structure:

The structure is defined on the (16-bit) MSP430 as follows:

```
typedef union _group_64 {
    float data_fp[2];  
    unsigned char data_u8[8];
    char data_8[8];
    unsigned int data_u16[4];
    int data_16[4];
    unsigned long data_u32[2];
    long data_32[2];
} group_64;
```

However, there were no specification of a language associated with the data. Will this cause issues when trying to read it in? I'm trying to read it in python, but I am having trouble identifying where to start.

I have tried using piping as recommended in a C struct to Python post but was unsuccessful so I am trying again from the beginning.

Comment: Do you have *actual code and data* that you need to interpret?  You probably want the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module but your question is too vague.  Edit the question and add an example.

Comment: @MarkTolonen The data is from a BMU that has not yet been connected to the code. I currently do not have any concrete data, but in the structure there will be data held there.

Comment: The structure is an 8-byte union. Use the `struct.unpack` function to unpack the type of data requested.